# Herança com Relacionamento de 0:N utilizando Nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Tenho a seguinte situação:

Pessoa

```
    public class Pessoa
{  
       public Pessoa()
       {
         Endereco = new List<Endereco>();  
        }    
    public virtual int IdPessoa { get; set; }
    public virtual string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Endereco> Endereco { get; set; }
 }
```

Mapa

```
    public class PessoaMap: ClassMap<Pessoa>
{

    public PessoaMap()
    {

        Id(x => x.IdPessoa);

        Map(x => x.Nome)
            .Not.Nullable()
            .Length(MapLength.Texto);

        HasMany<Endereco>(x => x.Endereco)
        .KeyColumn("TipodePessoa")
        .Cascade.All()
        .Inverse();


        Table("Pessoa");


    }
```

Endereço

```
   public class Endereco:Pessoa
{



    public virtual string Numero { get; set; }
    public virtual string Complemento { get; set; }
    public virtual string CEP { get; set; }
    public virtual string Cidade { get; set; }
    public virtual string UF { get; set; }
    public virtual string Pais { get; set; }
    public virtual Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }

}
```

Mapa

```
    public class PessoaEnderecoMap : SubclassMap<PessoaEndereco>
 {

    public PessoaEnderecoMap()
    {



        Table(@"PessoaEndereco");

        KeyColumn("IdPessoa");




         Map(x => x.Numero)
          .Not.Nullable()
          .Length(MapLength.TextoCurto);

         Map(x => x.Complemento)
         .Not.Nullable()
         .Length(MapLength.TextoCurto);

         Map(x => x.CEP)
         .Not.Nullable()
         .Length(MapLength.TextoCurto);

        Map(x => x.Cidade)
        .Not.Nullable()
        .Length(MapLength.TextoCurto);

        Map(x => x.UF)
       .Not.Nullable()
       .Length(MapLength.TextoCurto);

        Map(x => x.Pais)
       .Not.Nullable()
       .Length(MapLength.TextoCurto);

        References(x => x.Pessoa);

    }
}
```

PessoaCliente

```
    public class PessoaCliente : Pessoa
{  
    public virtual string Cnpj { get; set; }
    public virtual string InscrEstadual { get; set; }
    public virtual string Telefone { get; set; }

}
```

Mapa

```
 public class PessoaClienteMap : SubclassMap<PessoaCliente>
 {


    public PessoaClienteMap() {

        Table(@"PessoaCliente");

        KeyColumn("IdPessoa");

        Map(x => x.Cnpj)
         .Length(MapLength.TextoCurto);


        Map(x => x.InscrEstadual)
       .Length(MapLength.TextoCurto);

        Map(x => x.Telefone)
       .Length(MapLength.TextoCurto);


    }

 }
```

PessoaLogin

```
   public class PessoaLogin:Pessoa
{

    public virtual string Senha { get; set; }
}
```

Mapa

```
    public class PessoaLoginMap : SubclassMap<PessoaLogin> 
{

    public PessoaLoginMap()
    {

        KeyColumn("IdPessoa");

        Map(x => x.Senha)
            .Not.Nullable()
            .Length(MapLength.TextoMini);


        Table("PessoaLogin");


    }


}
```

Desse jeito tanto PessoaCliente e PessoaLogin recebe Endereço.  Com faço para

que PessoaCliente tenha dos dados de  Endereço e PessoaLogin não?

Poderia tirar Endereço da Classe Pai Pessoa, e  fazer a relação entre Endereço e PessoaCliente só que vou cair em outra problema de duplicidade de colunas
porque essa Classe Endereço, vai ser utilizando tambem em PessoaContato,PessoaFornecer,PessoaPerfil que herda de Pessoa.

Queria deixar Endereço sendo filha da classe Pessoa.

quando for construir PessoaCliente chamar lista de endereços que esta em Pessoa

quando for PessoaLogin não chamar a Lista de endereços que esta em Pessoa

quando for PessoaFornecer chamar a lista de endereços que esta em Pessoa

.... assim vai.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Sim, acho que eu posso te ajudar: 

**Deixe de lado essas heranças, elas vão te dar mais trabalho que solução.**

Por exemplo, em vez de *PessoaLogin*, crie uma classe *Usuário* e relacione-a com a *Pessoa*, sem herança.

Você não disse que atributos terão *PessoaCliente* e *PessoaFornecer*, mas provavelmente vale a mesma abordagem: classes distintas e relacionamentos em vez de herança.

Comment: Olá Caffé tem como vc me explicar como ficaria?

Answer (score 1):

O que eu apresento abaixo é uma solução de modelagem que não utiliza herança.

As mudanças que eu promovi na sua modelagem original foram:

- Endereço deixa de herdar de pessoa e passa a não herdar de coisa alguma.
- Removi o relacionamento de Endereço para Pessoa, pois um endereço não precisa conhecer quem mora ali, é a pessoa que tem que dizer onde ela mora.
- PessoaCliente passa a se chamar Cliente e não herda mais de Pessoa nem de coisa alguma.
- Cliente está relacionado à Pessoa. Este relacionamento não pode ser alterado pois um cliente nunca vai se transformar em outra pessoa, então a propriedade Pessoa é somente leitura. A maneira de setar a pessoa ali usando NHibernate eu não sei (eu usei o construtor).
- PessoaLogin passa a se chamar Usuário e também deixa de herdar de pessoa e passa a não herdar de ninguém.
- Usuário está relacionado à Pessoa. Eu assumi que este relacionamento também não pode ser alterado e usei a mesma solução que o relacionamento entre Cliente e Pessoa.

Ficou assim:

```
public class Pessoa
{  
    public virtual int IdPessoa { get; set; }
    public virtual string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Endereco> Endereco { get; set; }
}

public class Endereco
{
    public virtual string Numero { get; set; }
    public virtual string Complemento { get; set; }
    public virtual string CEP { get; set; }
    public virtual string Cidade { get; set; }
    public virtual string UF { get; set; }
    public virtual string Pais { get; set; }
}

public class Cliente
{  
    public Cliente(Pessoa pessoa)
    {
        this.Pessoa = pessoa;
    }
    public virtual Pessoa Pessoa { get;}
    public virtual string Cnpj { get; set; }
    public virtual string InscrEstadual { get; set; }
    public virtual string Telefone { get; set; }
}

public class Usuário
{
    public Usuario(Pessoa pessoa)
    {
        this.Pessoa = pessoa;
    }
    public virtual string NomeUsuario { get; set; }
    public virtual string Senha { get; set; }
    public virtual Pessoa Pessoa { get;}
}
```

Eu nunca usei NHibernate então não vou me arriscar pelo mapeamento das entidades - vou me restringir à modelagem das entidades já apresentada.